# How can I make certain fetch data appear after pressing a button. Using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button, fetch

I've pulled some data using an API and fetch. But I need some of the data to appear after pressing a button. I can get it to appear, but I'm having trouble making it appear with a button.

So I want the variable 'moreData' to be displayed on button click. I've thought about making another function, but then my fetch data is wonky, and such.
Here's my JS.

```
window.onload = function() {
    oneUser()
}


const oneUser = () => {
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then((response) => {
    getPic(response);
})

}

for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    oneUser();
}

const getPic = (response) => {
    // console.log(response.results.gender);
    let picText = `<div> <img src="${response.results[0].picture.large}"/> `;
    let info = `${response.results[0].name.first}, ${response.results[0].name.last}  `;
    let moreData = `${response.results[0].dob.date}, ${response.results[0].location.street.name}, ${response.results[0].location.street.number}</div>`;
    document.getElementById('picDiv').innerHTML += picText + info + moreData;

}
```

And my HTML

```
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="picDiv">
            <button id="buttonData" onclick="getPic()">More details</button>

    </div>

    <div id="dataDiv">


    </div>
```

I've had troubles in the past with buttons. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `<button id="buttonData" onclick="oneUser()">`

Comment: Store your `fetch` to variable like `const ftc = fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')`, then inside an  `EventListener` function use `ftc.then(()=>{})`.

Comment: Thank you @StaleMartyr. But that gives me more users. I just need the data in 'moreData' to be displayed on click. The DOB and street address and number.

Comment: @StackSlave would that work for moreData?

Comment: @hbrashid, Can you look at this example https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/QWbGLNE whether this is your expectation??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Yes! That seems to be what I need, thanks. However, I need it for each user.

Comment: @hbrashid, Will work on it.. Whether the more details button is common or for every user there will be a button?

Comment: Ridiculous use of template literals.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan. Yes for every user. Preferably next to their name, there needs to be a details button.

Comment: @hbrashid, Here you go https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/XWbNWJo ..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Thank you! Can you explain a bit what you did?

Comment: @hbrashid, Posted as answer with step by step explanation.. In the end assigning unique eventlistener to each button was complex and made it by passing the index and setting uniue id for each button.. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from here,

```
for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++){
    oneUser(i);
}
```

While calling the api inside for loop, pass index as well,

Then do api call as like yours,

```
function oneUser(i) {
  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
.then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
.then((response) => {
    getPic(response, i);
})
  .catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
})
}
```

with one change that passing the received index to the `getPic(i)` function..

Then in `getpic()`, have the same code as like you did for `picText`,  `info`, and `moreData` and append these to `picDiv` innerHTML..

```
  const picText = `<div> <img src="${response.results[0].picture.large}"/> `;

  const info = `${response.results[0].name.first}, ${response.results[0].name.last}  `;

  document.getElementById('picDiv').innerHTML += picText + info;

  const moreData = `<div id="moreData" style="display:none"> ${response.results[0].dob.date}, ${response.results[0].location.street.name}, ${response.results[0].location.street.number}</div>`;

  document.getElementById('picDiv').innerHTML += moreData;
```

Then create a button with unique `id` from received index `i`..

`<button id=moreData${i}>More details</button>`

Initially we are making the moreData section alone in display none like,

```
<div id="moreData" style="display:none">
```

and the complete function like,

```
function getPic(response, i){

  const picText = `<div> <img src="${response.results[0].picture.large}"/> `;

  const info = `${response.results[0].name.first}, ${response.results[0].name.last}  `;

  document.getElementById('picDiv').innerHTML += picText + info;

  const moreData = `<div id="moreData" style="display:none"> ${response.results[0].dob.date}, ${response.results[0].location.street.name}, ${response.results[0].location.street.number}</div>`;

  document.getElementById('picDiv').innerHTML += moreData;

  const button = `<button id=moreData${i}>More details</button> <br /><br />`;

  document.getElementById('picDiv').innerHTML += button;


  getMoreData();

}
```

At the end call `getMoreData()`, with same for loop you did first like,

```
function getMoreData(){
  for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    const elem = document.getElementById('moreData' + i);
    if(elem){
      elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('moreData' + i).previousSibling.style.display = "block"
        });
    }
}
}
```

In this above function we are making the `moredata` to be displayed once clicking on the more details button by adding unique eventlistener to each button..

> [**Working Example**](https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/XWbNWJo)